# How to remove at most one object from nsmutablearray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to insert a bunch of objects into a NSMutableArray. Then I would remove them one by one when the time fits. Every inserted objects must be removed.

However, if I have several copies of the same object, I just want to remove one of them.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [@[@1, @1, @5, @6, @5] mutableCopy]; // a copy of your array
NSMutableSet *removedObjects = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:arr];
for (id obj in removedObjects) {
    [arr removeObjectAtIndex:[arr indexOfObject:obj]]; // removes the first identical object
}
```

Also note that if your array is filled with custom objects, you need to implements `hash` and `isEqual:` so the comparisons can work.

Answer (score 1):

are any of these functions what you are looking for?

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)];
[array removeLastObject];
[array removeObject:(id)];
```

Comment: `removeObject:` removes all instances of an object. The other two are what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
[myMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex: 0];
```

or

```
[myMutableArray removeLastObject];
```

To remove the first and last objects respectively.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good design for `[NSMutableArray removeObject:]` to remove all the occurences but we can avoid it by first getting an index using `indexOfObject:` and then removing the object using `removeObjectAtIndex:`

Answer (score 0):

i prefer using index of object; it will return the index of object first appeared in the array

```
 NSMutableArray * first = [@[@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"] mutableCopy];//your first array

    NSMutableArray * willBeAppend =  [@[@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5"] mutableCopy];//new objects to append

    [first addObjectsFromArray:willBeAppend];//append new objects

    id objectToBeRemoved = @"3";// object will be removed

    NSInteger objIx = [first indexOfObject:objectToBeRemoved];// index of object

    if (objIx != NSNotFound) {

        [first removeObjectAtIndex:objIx]; //remove object


        NSLog(@"%@",first);

    }
```